# Change tracker proper handle

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Actually I have two entities added to my `DbContext`, but if I press the cancel button I must delete it.

How can I do that?

There is a method something like this:

```
dbContext.Entry(MyEntity).Remove();
```

I need this because in the next document after cancel, my old entities could be saved by mistake.

Things that I tried:

- Change the `Added` state to `Unchanged` but it throw a exception.

**Update 1:** Generally I Create a new instance and add it to the context

```
MyEntityType entity = new MyEntityType();
dbContext.MyEntityType.Add(entity);
```

Comment: Do you `.Save()`? or just insert things in the context without saving on the 'Add' action?

Comment: Tks. just Add without save

Comment: It all depends very much on how you add the entities and how you change the state. Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Gert please see the update.

Comment: You can set the state to `Detached`, but I agree with the answer that you better dispose the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click cancel you should do what you need to do and then create a **new** context when it's **needed**.  For some reason there is a population of programmers that only use 1 context.  The context should be opened, objects added, attached, deleted etc.. then Saved and then **closed**.  They shouldn't be open for long standing amounts of time.

If you are using the dbContext to manage a collection of objects that will be saved later (indeterminate length of time) then use some other collection to store them.  Then when you are ready to save the changes create your context, add, attach, delete and save; then promptly close.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `Added` state to `Detached` instead of `Unchanged`.

Try to read [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676).